# Search for words (exact matches) in multiple texts using Python

Tags: python, regex, search

I want to let the user choose and open multiple texts and perform a search for exact matches in the texts.
I want the encoding to be unicode.

If I search for "cat" I want it to find "cat", "cat,", ".cat" but not "catalogue".

I don't know how to let the user search for two words ("cat" OR "dog") in all of the texts at the same time??????
Maybe I can use RE?

So far I have just made it possible for the user to insert the path to the directory containing the text files to search in. Now I want to let the user (raw_input) search for two words in all of the texts, and then print and save the results (e.g. "search_word_1" and "search_word_2" found in document1.txt, "search_word_2" found in document4.txt) in a separate document (search_words).

```
import re, os


path = raw_input("insert path to directory :")
ex_library = os.listdir(path)
search_words = open("sword.txt", "w") # File or maybe list to put in the results
thelist = []

for texts in ex_library:
    f = os.path.join(path, texts)
    text = open(f, "r")
    textname = os.path.basename(texts)
    print textname
    for line in text.read():

    text.close()
```

Comment: What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: `for names in textname.split():` will just give you a list of characters in the base name of the file. you need to change that to: `for line in text.read():` and then you will iterate over the lines in the text file.

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable name.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It is fine to use `file` as a variable name. There is no `file` builtin in Python 3. And you should always use `open` to open a file instead of `file`. A case then you need to create a subclass of `file` is rare.

Comment: Here's an very simple version of recursive grep in python: https://gist.github.com/4387573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are appropriate tool in this case.

> I want it to find "cat", "cat,", ".cat" but not "catalogue".

Pattern: `r'\bcat\b'`

`\b` matches at a word boundary.

> how to let the user search for two words ("cat" OR "dog") in all of the texts at the same time

Pattern: `r'\bcat\b|\bdog\b'`

To print `"filename: <words that are found in it>"`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

def fgrep(words, filenames, encoding='utf-8', case_insensitive=False):
    findwords = re.compile("|".join(r"\b%s\b" % re.escape(w) for w in words),
                           flags=re.I if case_insensitive else 0).findall
    for name in filenames:
        with open(name, 'rb') as file:
             text = file.read().decode(encoding)
             found_words = set(findwords(text))
             yield name, found_words

def main():
    words = [w.decode(sys.stdin.encoding) for w in sys.argv[1].split(",")]
    filenames = sys.argv[2:] # the rest is filenames
    for filename, found_words in fgrep(words, filenames):
        print "%s: %s" % (os.path.basename(filename), ",".join(found_words))

main()
```

Example:

```
$ python findwords.py 'cat,dog' /path/to/*.txt
```

#### Alternative solutions

To avoid reading the whole file in memory:

```
import codecs

...
with codecs.open(name, encoding=encoding) as file:
    found_words = set(w for line in file for w in findwords(line))
```

You could also print found words in the context they are found e.g., print lines with highlighted words:

```
from colorama import init  # pip install colorama
init(strip=not sys.stdout.isatty())  # strip colors if stdout is redirected
from termcolor import colored  # pip install termcolor

highlight = lambda s: colored(s, on_color='on_red', attrs=['bold', 'reverse'])

...
regex = re.compile("|".join(r"\b%s\b" % re.escape(w) for w in words),
                   flags=re.I if case_insensitive else 0)

for line in file:
    if regex.search(line): # line contains words
       line = regex.sub(lambda m: highlight(m.group()), line)
       yield line
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot. I understand most of what's going on in the first example, but i'm confused about the case sensitivity. I've tried it and when I search for "cat" it finds "cat" but not "Cat"

Comment: Maybe I just have to put True instead of False? def fgrep(words, filenames, encoding='utf-8', case_insensitive=True):

Comment: @user1921937: Supply the argument in the main when you call it: `for filename, found_words in fgrep(words, filenames, case_insensitive=True): ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the text in each file on whitespace and punctuation. Once that's done you can simply look for the words you are searching for in the remaining list. You also need to convert everything to lowercase, unless you also want case sensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Some (maybe useful) information in addition to the existing answers:

You should be aware that what the user means when he thinks of a "character" (=grapheme) is not always the same as a Unicode character, and some graphemes can be represented by Unicode characters in more than one unique way (e.g. composite character vs. base character + combining mark).

To do a search based on graphemes (=what the user expects in most cases) and not on specific Unicode character sequences, you need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization) your strings before you search.